# Libreoffice Calc adds extra commas or semicolons to formulas and doesn't return the answer

Tags: linux, libreoffice-calc

I am using

> LibreOffice 3.5.4.2 
>   Build ID: 350m1(Build:2)

On a Debian Jessie machine.

Whenever I input any inbuilt calc/excel function, it adds random commas (sometimes semicolumns) between the function and it's arguments and evaluate to either

> FEUILLE508

or

> FEUILLE509

What is happening? How can I fix it?
I can't find any similar situation on the internet. I restarted calc, restarted my computer, tried to upgrade calc, upgraded from debian wheezy to jessie, nothing works!

Here is what my input looks like:

[image]

and then if I press enter it adds random commas to my input:
[image]

Anyone have any ideas as to what to the problem might be??

**EDIT:**

If I change the User Interface to English(USA) the problem goes away.

Comment: This looks like corruption.  I would try reinstalling LO.

Comment: Yes, I didn't consider this to be an answer, just diagnostic info because it should work regarless of language settings.  I should add that in the configs I had ticked the box to use the formula names in english (when then user language was french), but I also tried using the French function names and the problem was the same.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling to rule out corruption?  If not corruption, it could be a bug.  The behavior makes no sense in any language.